# How can I pass the result from a function of one class to another?

Tags: c++, class

So I have 2 classes namely, **ForceSolver** and **FrictionContact**. I would like to pass the result (10) of the variable `force` from a function of **class ForceSolver** to **class FrictionContact**. For example:

**class ForceSolver**

```
class ForceSolver
{
    public:
        int force;
        int mass = 5;
        int acceleration = 2;

        void solveSystem ();
    };

void ForceSolver::solveSystem()
{
    force = mass * acceleration;
    std::cout << "Force is: " << force;
}
```

**class FrictionContact**

```
class FrictionContact : public ForceSolver
{
public:
    void printForce();
};

void FrictionContact::printForce()
{
    //print force;
    std::cout << force;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    FrictionContact contact;
   
    contact.printForce();
}
```

I would like to know how to achieve this.

Comment: `force` is not a local variable, this is a class member and available in the child class. What issue do you observe?

Comment: @S.M. Yes , you're right. I forgot to remove the "*" but this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Before calling printForce, you need to call solveSystem.

Comment: You need to call `solveSystem()` somewhere for computing `force`, either in main, or in `printForce()`, or in the parent constructor.

Comment: @S.M. I would like to get the result of ```force``` which is 10 and print that in FrictionContact but I'm not getting this result

Comment: @S.M. Right, is there a way I can do this without calling ```solveSysem()```  ?

Comment: There is no result until you call solveSystem.

Comment: @S.M. Okay, thank you

Comment: Is this the same question as [Getting null for data values from inherited class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70140442/getting-null-for-data-values-from-inherited-class)? Consider either close the original one, or edit the original one.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Yes it is. Okay

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `solveSystem()`?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Yes,  because actually ```solveSystem``` takes parameters. So when I call this function, I don't know which data to pass. Does this make sense? I can post a picture for clarification

Comment: Seems like all you need to get `force` is by multiplying `mass` and `acceleration`. Can't you do that in `printForce`?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep The framework I'm using doesn't calculate the forces in a straightforward manner but thanks anyway!

Comment: So `force` must be calculated with `solveSystem`? Then how do you expect it to be calculated without using `solveSystem`?

Answer (score 0):

I think before `printForce()` you should do `solveSystem()`, otherwise, the uninitialized value will be printed

```cpp
class ForceSolver
{
public:
    int force;
    int mass = 5;
    int acceleration = 2;

    void solveSystem ();
};

void ForceSolver::solveSystem()
{
    force = mass * acceleration;
    // std::cout << "Force is: " << force;
}

class FrictionContact : public ForceSolver
{
public:
    void printForce();
};

void FrictionContact::printForce()
{
    // print force;
    std::cout << force;
}

int main()
{
    FrictionContact contact;
    contact.solveSystem();
    contact.printForce();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).